# Getting App Photos with Facebook C# SDK

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

Using the Facebook C# SDK on Windows Phone 7, my mobile application can successfully upload apps to a user's photo album with a post to me/photos.  Those photos do not show up when I query the application's photos collection via the graph API using applicationId/photos query.  Any suggestions?  What permissions are necessary for this?  I am getting back an empty data set.

In the following code sample, accesstoken is the access token and 112233445666 is my Facebook application Id.

```
var client = new FacebookClient("accesstoken");

client.GetAsync("112233445666/photos", new Facebook.FacebookAsyncCallback(delegate(Facebook.FacebookAsyncResult asyncResult)
                {
                     var result = asyncResult.Result as JsonObject;

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Application Photos: {0}", result);
                }));
```

Comment: How have you confirmed that the images have been successfully been uploaded? Are the responses being cached? - What have you done to investigate/confirm this?

Comment: I can see them on the Facebook Photos page in the profile I upload them to.  They are labeled as being from my application.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are uploading pictures to the user's photo gallery, but you are querying  the application's photos? there is a difference. You want to query something like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{USERID}/albums
```

It wouldn't make sense that you are writing an app that stores EVERYONE's photos in the application's image gallery or is that what you are doing?

Comment: PS. Please mark my answer as the correct answer is I am correct (I need the reputation bump)